# How do I program the " $ time ./a.out " command?

Tags: c, macos, time, terminal

How do I program the `$ time ./a.out` command into my program so you only have to run `$ ./a.out` and the time will be displayed? I don't want to use the method below because the numbers change every time I run the program.

```
clock_t begin = clock();

/* Program to run and timed */

clock_t end = clock();

double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Also, I want to display the CPU program run time as well as the total run time including user input time. I don't know if it is possible to do.

Any idea?

Comment: On POSIX platforms (like macOS) then the difference between two calls to [`clock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html) will give you the elapsed CPU time. If you want the wall-clock time use e.g. [`clock_gettime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html).

Comment: Your program takes a different amount of time to run each time…

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can I have an example of how to use the gettimeofday feature to display the program run time? Is it some sort of gettimeofday (before) subtracted from gettimeofday (after)?

Comment: My first version of the comment used `gettimeofday` but it's obsolete. Use `clock_gettime` instead. But if you want an example of how to take the difference between two timestamps (as given from either `gettimeofday` or `clock_gettime`) there are plenty if you just [*search a little*](https://www.google.se/search?q=clock_gettime+difference+example).